# How to center text in circle using JQuery or CSS or both?

Tags: jquery, css, text, center, geometry

How to center text in circle using JQuery or CSS or both?
It's a navigation list item. Text can be one line or multiple line in the circle.
[Link-this is what i need to fix](http://goo.gl/XDxrdv)

Comment: use jQuery to calculate the height of the H3 and position the text accordingly. Nothing you can do retroactively in CSS about multiple lines of text without expressions, which are advised against.

Answer (score 1):

**Changed CSS**

```
.ch-info h3 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('div.ch-info').each(function () {
    var h = ( $(this).height() - $(this).children('h3').outerHeight() ) / 2;
    $(this).children('h3').css('margin-top', h + 'px');

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/eP8AN/)